# Performance/memory issues on marker clusters in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, markerclusterer

I am using this sample code to add a cluster of markers and infoWindows (and related event listeners) to my map:

```
 function initMap(locations) {
    var myLatLng = {lat: 41.69906, lng: 12.39258};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 5,
      center: myLatLng,
       mapTypeControl: false,
       scaleControl: false
    });

    var infoWin = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location
      });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) {
          content = <..some HTML content...>;
          infoWin.setContent(content);
          infoWin.open(map, marker);
       })
      return marker;
    });
```

The "`locations`" variable contains around 1,000 markers with lat/long and name. 
The question is: are 1,000 markers too much in terms of performance/memory load? How can I free memory when the application leaves the map to show other data?

Comment: depend  on the client resuorce but 1000 markers is  not an high number . And  you can't free resource, these are managed by browser  itself.

Comment: ok, but why the downvote?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter ..  for me your question is a valid question  ..